# Find if file exists inside a zip file using libzip and c++

Tags: c++, zip

How can I find if a specific file exists inside a zip file?

I'm using the following code, `zip *z` returns to a valid zip file but `zip_stat` always returns -1 even if the file exists in the archive inside a folder named .jsdos.

```
void Backend::zipTest() {
    int err = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open("archive.zip", 0, &err);
    const char *name = "myfile.txt";
    struct zip_stat st;
    zip_stat_init(&st);
    if (zip_stat(z, name, 0, &st) == 0) {
        qDebug() << "Is a valid zip file";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Not a valid zip file";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what ZIP archive library you're using (doesn't Qt have such functionality in its framework?) but have you tried to give the *full* path to the file (including directories)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the archive get's opened since the err variable doesn't change to `-1` but the `zip_stat` function is the issue

Comment: It got fixed now? For some unknown reason. Haven't really changed anything except I was trying to print a debug string

Comment: According libzip documentation (https://libzip.org/documentation/), I think you should use `zip_get_num_entries` function to get the total count of entries in zip cdr, then use `zip_get_name ` within a loop and compare each entries with the file you are looking for.

Comment: I mean the full path to the file *inside* the archive. I.e. `name` should be the path to the file, including the directories.